# Where clause on Heroku (Postgres) breaks but works fine locally (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, postgresql, heroku

I have the following line of code which works fine locally, but breaks when pushed to Production (Heroku):

```
def self.find_unresolved_with_approved_client
  self.joins(:client).where('clients.approved = true AND wish.status <> "Resolved"')
end
```

The error in my heroku logs is as follows:

```
2012-04-09T11:49:14+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (PGError: ERROR:  column "Resolved" does not exist
2012-04-09T11:49:14+00:00 app[web.1]:     16:       %th{ :class => :span10 } Subject
2012-04-09T11:49:14+00:00 app[web.1]:     17:       %th{ :class => :span4 } Status
2012-04-09T11:49:14+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: ...ERE (clients.approved = true AND wishes.status != "Resolved"...
2012-04-09T11:49:14+00:00 app[web.1]: : SELECT  "wishes".* FROM "wishes" INNER JOIN "clients" ON "clients"."id" = "wishes"."client_id" WHERE (clients.approved = true AND wishes.status != "Resolved") ORDER BY wishes.id LIMIT 25 OFFSET 0):
```

Why is it trying to make a column comparison on Production when it makes a literal comparison locally?

Comment: Yup, migrated, seeded - it didn't work.
So I reset the database, migrated again and seeds - no luck.
Then I tried restarting my application, still no dice.

Comment: It's the double quotes.  SQL standard says "label" is for things like columns and tables, while 'value' is for values.  MySQL, of course, does things a little differently.

So change "Resolved" to 'Resolved' and you should be ok.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation as to why it does it - I must go read SQL standards and stop relying on my experience with MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change the query to .where('clients.approved = ? AND wish.status != ?', true, 'Resolved')
This leaves the adaptor to build the query for you, which should fix the problem where different database having slightly different query syntax